# C# - Listview update subsitems for an item

Tags: c#, listview

I've a listview with the drone's ip, current position and desired position. My only problem is that when current position or desired position are updated, it adds a new drone with the same ip. I just want to update the values of current position and desired position for that particular ip.

```
            ip_drone_master = this.master.ip_dron();
            ip_drone_slave = this.slave.ip_dron();

            PointF posicao_master = master.pos_atual();
            posicao_atual_master = posicao_master;

            PointF posicao_slave = slave.pos_atual();
            posicao_atual_slave = posicao_slave;

            pos_atual_master = " X: " + posicao_atual_master.X + " Y: " + posicao_atual_master.Y;
            pos_atual_slave = " X: " + posicao_atual_slave.X + " Y: " + posicao_atual_slave.Y;

            pos_desej_master = " X:  " + posicao_desejada_master.X + " Y:  " + posicao_desejada_master.Y;
            pos_desej_slave = " X:  " + posicao_desejada_slave.X + " Y:  " + posicao_desejada_slave.Y;

            ListViewItem item_master = lv_lista_posicoes.FindItemWithText(pos_atual_master);
            ListViewItem item_slave = lv_lista_posicoes.FindItemWithText(pos_atual_slave);

            ListViewItem item_master_desej = lv_lista_posicoes.FindItemWithText(pos_desej_master);
            ListViewItem item_slave_desej = lv_lista_posicoes.FindItemWithText(pos_desej_slave);


            if (item_master != null && item_master_desej != null)
            {

            }
            else
            {

                ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem(ip_drone_master);
                lv.SubItems.Add(pos_atual_master);
                lv.SubItems.Add(pos_desej_master);                 
                lv_lista_posicoes.Items.Add(lv);


            }
```

Comment: This line `ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem(ip_drone_master);` is creating a new `ListViewItem` every time. Did you mean to search whether the item exists first using `lv_lista_posicoes.FindItemWithText(ip_drone_master)`

Comment: so if exists i dont add?

Comment: Yeah....if that's the behaviour you require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're creating a new `ListViewItem` every time when you need to find the item and update it.

Try changing this:

```
            ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem(ip_drone_master);
            lv.SubItems.Add(pos_atual_master);
            lv.SubItems.Add(pos_desej_master);                 
            lv_lista_posicoes.Items.Add(lv);
```

to this:

```
            var lvCheck = lv_lista_posicoes.FindItemWithText(ip_drone_master);
            ListViewItem lv = lvCheck ?? new ListViewItem(ip_drone_master);
            lv.SubItems.Add(pos_atual_master);
            lv.SubItems.Add(pos_desej_master); 
            if (lvCheck == null) lv_lista_posicoes.Items.Add(lv);
```

Comment: ListViewItem lv = lvCheck ?? new ListViewItem(ip_drone_master); What does the question marks do?

Comment: `??` is a binary null check and assignment operator. So `var x = y ?? z;` means `if (y == null) x=y; else x=z;`

Comment: basically it means if it doesnt exist. create

Comment: Yes. That's what this answer will do. I assumed from the question that this is the behaviour you require.